Bybit - demo WS create order
I am trying to place order through WebSocket on Bybit DEMO.
I get OK, but when I am trying to send order it returns:

"retMsg": "API key is invalid."

even though the auth was OK.
Currently I am using this endpoint: wss://stream.bybit.com/v5/trade
Here is log from my app.
Received:
{"retCode":0,"retMsg":"OK","op":"auth","connId":"crbb0c7flflsaujhnv00-vm86"}
Connected!
Sent: 
            {
                "header": {
                    "demo":"true",
                    "X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP": "1725787282942"
                },
                "op": "order.create",
                "args": [
                    {
                        "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
                        "side": "Buy",
                        "orderType": "Market",
                        "qty": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
Received: {"retCode":10003,"retMsg":"API key is invalid.","op":"order.create","data":{},"header":{"Traceid":"55c8108cf76d971a47f58b66fb97b05d","Timenow":"1725787282421"},"connId":"crbb0c7flflsaujhnv00-vm86"}

Correct endpoint or example for DEMO order place
